# Problem with heroku db:pull while at work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, taps

When I try to pull down a database while at work I get the following error:

```
:>heroku db:pull 
Auto-detected local database: sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 
Bad credentials given for http://heroku:[hidden]@taps.heroku.com
```

Note that when I am at home I am able to run this command just fine. I wanted to know if you have any suggestions for common reasons I would get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to perform other Heroku commands whilst at work? If you aren't then it's probably a problem with your SSH keys. See this [Heroku help document](http://docs.heroku.com/keys) for details.